# How do you load images in a simple Java Project?

Tags: java

I have this structure in my project:

[image]

and my code is simply this:

```
public class ChapterTwo {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            //File imageFile = new File("../../../../resources/lena.jpg");
            String image = ChapterTwo.class.getResource("resources/lena.jpg").toExternalForm();
            System.out.println(image);
            //MBFImage image = ImageUtilities.readMBF(imageFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now this has been driving me crazy. how hard is it to make java locate an image in a simple directory structure?

I tried:

```
resources/lena.jpg
/resources/lena.jpg
../resources/lena.jpg
../../../../../resources/lena.jpg
```

nothing works. When I load the File and call `exists()` it always returns false. How do I load this image?

PS: My code is just testing code, but you get the idea, I was trying various stuff.
And it is `com.foo` not `com`

EDIT:
From the answers:

```
String imagePath = ChapterTwo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("lena.jpg").toExternalForm();
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
System.out.println(imageFile.exists());
```

I get `false` ....

Comment: You should try `./../../../resources/lena.jpg`, just in the sub-directory of three directory above your current directory.

Comment: it is actually com.foo. So should I add another ".." ?

Comment: I don't see any foo in the image hierarchy. WHich directory contains foo inside?

Comment: This is my full path, src/main/java/com/foo/ch2/ChapterTwo.java

Comment: don't use `toExternalForm()`, use `getPath()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String image = ChapterTwo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("lena.jpg").getPath();
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't use `toExternalForm()` to check file existence, use `getPath()`

Comment: Note: this works because you use maven as a build tool, which puts everything in `src/main/resources` in the classpath. The given line of code looks a bit odd - usually you don't get the classloader: `getClass().getResource("/lena.jpg").toPath();`.